# How to add unique objects to List without doing a costly !IEnumerable.Any()

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am receiving a range of objects through an Observable. The objects coming in could be duplicate based on their PartNumber property, so I have to check to make sure I don't get duplicates in the list. I am getting millions of part numbers so any query in the list would be costly so we don't want to run frequent queries.

Here is the implementation of OnNext

```
void OnNext(Product p)
{
 if (!products.Any(x => x.PartNumber.Equals(p))) /// Very costly query
 {
    products.Add(p);
 {
}
```

For every object I receive, I have to run that costly query to make sure I am not adding duplicates... Is there any other way to save the horse-power ?

Comment: Make `Products` a `HashTable<T>`. Make sure to override `PartNumber.GetHashCode()` accordingly.

Comment: You should use a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Either use your own `HashSet<T>`, or just use the Rx `Distinct` operator (which uses a HashSet internally):

```
productSource.Distinct(part => part.PartNumber).Subscribe(OnNext);
```

Comment: Does that work on particular property or object reference?  Also my observable is hot

Comment: yes just use the `Distinct` overload that lets you pass a key selector method: `source.Distinct(t => t.Key)`.